# How to check if the input is emoji without using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, java, dom

I'm new to web development and just trying to check if the user input contains emojis without using regex for performance reasons.
Is there a way to do it with JavaScript on the front end or by using java on the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Java does not identify emoji as such

The official [*Unicode Character Database*](http://www.unicode.org/ucd/) does *not* identify emoji characters as such, according to [Annex A](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/index.html#Emoji_Properties_and_Data_Files) of [*Unicode® Technical Standard #51 UNICODE EMOJI*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/index.html).

I suppose that is why we do not see any kind of `isEmoji` method on the Java 13 class, [`Character`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html).

## Roll-your-own

According to that Annex A, there are [`emoji-data`](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/index.html#emoji_data) data files available describing aspects of emoji characters. If you are sufficiently motivated to reliably identify emoji characters, I suggest reading that Technical Note, and consider importing the data from those files to identify the [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of emoji. There may well be ranges of numbers that the Unicode Consortium uses to cluster the emoji characters.

Keep in mind that the Unicode Consortium in recent years has been frequently adding more and more emoji. So you will be chasing a moving target, needing updates.

You may be able to narrow down your ranges with the named ranges of code points defined in [`Character.UnicodeBlock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html).

I am guessing that [`Character.OTHER_SYMBOL`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#OTHER_SYMBOL) may help, as the emoji I perused are so tagged, according to the handy macOS app, [*UnicodeChecker*](https://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/index.html).

FYI, the Unicode Consortium does publish a list of emoji: [*Full Emoji List, v12.0*](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

By the way, the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/#TOC-What-is-CLDR-) published by the Unicode Consortium and used by default in recent versions of Java defines how to sort emoji. Yes, [emoji have sort-order](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-ordering.html): human faces before cat faces, and so on. The code points for emoji characters are assigned rather arbitrarily, so do not go by that for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to blacklist emojis, it'd probably be easier to whitelist the characters you do want to allow. If your site is multilingual, you'd have to add the characters of the languages you want to support. It should be relatively simple to loop over each character of your input and see if it's in the list of valid characters.

You'll want to do your validation on both the frontend and the backend. You want to do the frontend so you can show feedback to the user immediately, and you have to do validation on the backend so that people can't game your system by opening their browser's console or getting creative. Frontend stuff should never be trusted by the server in general.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. What I want to do is actually read the emojis and maybe save them to the database. But I don't know if that is possible

Comment: Ah, in that case a whitelist won't work for you. Seems like a pretty weird thing to do though. Like, what possible use could you have for a database of emojis that users have tried to use?

Comment: I was just thinking about if it was possible for like a key=value pair that I can store in the database, where the "key" is an emoji.

Comment: Anything is possible, I'm just curious why you would want to do that.